# Retrieve Information from OLAP

Tags: php, laravel-5

i need to know how to connect MS OLAP Cube with php, i am using Laravel 5.2 Framework, I am really confused at the moment, I am very new to all this just being learning Data warehousing and php, any help and recommendations will be appreciated

Comment: Your first step would be to make sure that your Database Driver for PHP is installed. After that, you'll want to configure your connection details in the `config/database.php` file. The Laravel documentation has a pretty comprehensive guide on how to begin with Database queries in the application: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database - I'd suggest walking through a couple of examples there to help you get the feel of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your second post, please do not migrate your Data Warehouse to MySQL.
A data warehouse is definitely not suited for MySQL. Apart from the fact that you've have multiple copies of your data (along with many costly ETL procedures), MySQL is not a serious OLAP database.

It is possible to have Multiple Databases. This answer for Laravel 4 has a tutorial. http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections  (It may be slightly different in Laravel 5.2)